# Crashlytics not Sending Crash Reports [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I have added Crashlytics into my iOS app via Fabric for providing crash reports. I've followed the instructions given with Fabric, placed the Fabric calling method last in applicationDidFinishLaunching and verified that my dYSM is up to date. When my app crashes on my iPhone 6 the crash is logged and reported fine. I also have a beta distributed using Fabric's beta testing service to a few friends. For some reason at least one of them has been experiencing crashes on an iPhone 4s and I haven't received a single report for this device. Is there a common cause for such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

As a sanity make sure that you and your tester have allowed crash reports to be sent. Go to Settings->Privacy->Diagnostics & Usage and dust accordingly.